# Is it good Practice to start em-websocket with rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket

for my Rails-App I need to call all connected clients if new data is uploaded. So I want to use websockets. Currently I have created a new file in initializers which starts the socket server in an new thread:

```
require 'em-websocket'

$websocket_clients = []

Thread.new do
  EventMachine.run {
    EventMachine::WebSocket.start(:host => "0.0.0.0", :port => 8080) do |ws|
      ws.onopen {
        $websocket_clients << ws
      }

      ws.onclose {
        $websocket_clients.delete(ws)
      }

    end
  }
end
```

So I can use

```
$websocket_clients.each do |ws|
  ws.send "text"
end
```

in my controller.
My question now is: Is this good practice or will I experience any probelms with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may cause problems when you depoly your application. When you deploy your application, you are usually forking multiple worker processes which each handle requests - at least in the two most popular servers (Phusion Passenger and unicorn).

Each server will try to start a websocket thread. The first one starts smoothly, the next ones will probably crash, because the port is blocked by the first one. If you fix this problem and you are just using the code to distribute messages to the clients, as posted above, it will probably work without major problems.

However problems will arise if you start to query your database, as long as you do not enable thread safety in ActiveRecord. When the websocket part of your application gets larger, you can put it into an extra daemon that handles requests seperately from the server processes.